# What is the higher version of Log4j2 supported by Spring boot 2.0.9

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

In our project, we are planning to use Spring boot 2.0.9 version. I would like to know what is the higher version of Log4j2 supported by Spring framework 2.0.9?

Comment: maven repository : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.0.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn dependency:tree
gradle dependencies
```

Those commands will show you the which dependecy is used when spring boot is added to pom or gradle file.

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.9.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.10.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.26
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.9.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.13.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.8
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.8
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.9.8
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.0.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.39
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:8.5.39
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.39
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.39
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.39 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.16.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.0.13.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.13.RELEASE (*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has no restrictions on what version of Log4j you can use with it. spring-boot-starter-logging-log4j2 comes prepackaged with a specific version of log4j2. If you want to use a newer version do not include spring-boot-starter-logging-log4j2 as a dependency and instead include the log4j-bom as a dependency in your dependency management and then include the specific log4j artifacts you want to include, without the version specified on the dependency.

For example:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have a project using log4j-over slf4j 1.7.25 JAR as part of Spring boot starter kit. And spring version is 1.4.0. Is it possible to update to log4j-slf4j-impl -2.16 with the same spring version?